# Cola de edición llena

Tags: discusión

Parece que hay demasiadas ediciones pendientes y muy pocos moderadores.

> En este momento, la cola de edición está llena; inténtalo de nuevo en
>   unos minutos.

Para tener gente con más experiencia no artificial (como el caso de las traducciones) sugiero que se permita temporalmente una consesión de permisos a un límite menor de privilegios de los normales para que un porcentaje mayor pueda hacer tareas de moderación.

En concreto pienso que hay mucho que hacer en *edición de etiquetas*, y creación de *sinónimos de etiquetas*.

Comment: Lo mismo pienso yo, he estado trabajando en la edición de las etiquetas, los sinónimos y las Wikis y me he sentido muy limitado por este inconveniente.

Answer (score 4):

La reputación requerida para obtener estos privilegios ya está bastante baja para sitios en beta:

- 350 para obtener acceso a las colas de revisión (500 en el SO inglés)
- 500 para editar preguntas y respuestas (2000 en el SO inglés)
- 750 para aprobar revisiones de las tag wikis (5000 en el SO inglés)
- 1250 para crear sinónimos (2500 en el SO inglés)

Sólo necesitamos esperar unas semanas, y tendremos más usuarios con la reputación requerida. No creo que es necesario pedir a los 
desarrolladores ocupados hacer cambios para arreglar una situación que va a cambiar naturalmente muy pronto.

Comment: pues proporcionalmente a los usuarios que se tienen no. Saludos.